# Weighted Random Selection Based on Date

Tags: c#

I have an existing windows app that displays a message on screen on set time interval. The message is selected randomly from a SQL Server database making sure each message is displayed only once for the current day by marking the message with current date. The table structure is as follows:

```
Id int
Text nvarchar
LastDateUsed datetime
```

I am hoping to improve the existing code by making the logic to select a message so those messages which have been used more recently will be less likely to get selected.

My existing code to randomly select a message is as follows:

```
IQueryable<Message> filteredMessages = db.Messages;

var currentDate = DateTime.Today;
IQueryable<int> filteredMessageIds = filteredMessages.Where(x => x.LastDateUsed < currentDate).Select(x => x.Id);
int filteredMessagesCount = filteredMessageIds.Count();

// Select one Id
int selectedId = filteredMessageIds.ToList()[SelectRandomIndex(filteredMessagesCount)];

// Display selected message
DisplayMessage(selectedId)


private static int SelectRandomIndex(int filteredMessagesCount)
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int selectedIndex = rnd.Next(1, filteredMessagesCount - 1);

    return selectedIndex;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't call `Random rnd = new Random();` inside a method. That means that if you call the method rapidly the same seed may be used for `rnd` and you'll get repeated values.

Comment: Also, the two parameters for the `.Next(...)` call are a minimum value and an **exclusive** maximum value. So, if you want to randomly select values from `filteredMessageIds.ToList()` then you need to call `rnd.Next(0, filteredMessagesCount)`.

Comment: And, calling `filteredMessageIds.Count()` and then `filteredMessageIds.ToList()` on your `IQueryable<int> filteredMessageIds` will cause two calls to the database. It is best to assign the `.ToList()` to a new variable, before calling `.Count()` on that.

Comment: However, it may be better for you to keep the current `.Count()`/`.ToList()` code and change `int selectedId = filteredMessageIds.ToList()[SelectRandomIndex(filteredMessagesCount)];` to `int selectedId = filteredMessageIds.ElementAt(SelectRandomIndex(filteredMessagesCount));` instead. Try both.

Comment: Your `.Where(x => x.LastDateUsed < currentDate)` doesn't make sense. It's selecting `x` where it was last used in the past and ignoring those last used in the future?

Comment: @Enigmativity thanks for the suggestions. The "where" clause is supposed to prevent displaying messages that are already displayed today.

Comment: @Enigmativity it also doesn't matter if Random rnd = new Random() inside a method return repeated values. the "where" clause makes it sure no message will be displayed more than once.

Comment: Yes, it's fair enough in this particular case, but it is certainly a good practice to use a single instance of `Random` (per thread if applicable) for your application, and failing that a class-level variable is better than a method-level one.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the number of messages, and the days since they were last displayed, isn't too high then this code works:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int selectedId =
    db
        .Messages
        .Where(x => x.LastDateUsed < DateTime.Today)
        .Select(x => new { x.Id, x.LastDateUsed })
        .ToArray()
        .SelectMany(x =>
            Enumerable.Repeat(x.Id, DateTime.Today.Subtract(x.LastDateUsed).Days))
        .OrderBy(x => rnd.Next())
        .Concat(new [] { -1 })
        .First();
```

The main part of this code that gives you what you want is the `.SelectMany(...)`. It repeats the `Id` for each message by the number of days since the message was last used. So a message last used 7 days ago has 7x the chance of being picked that one used one day ago.

The `OrderBy` is slightly wasteful, and you do need to check for `-1` to see if there were no messages, but it should do fine.

Comment: thanks for the suggested solution, I'm going to try it out later.